# Parsing Exception error when using Terms in ElasticSearch

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I'm getting an error on this elastic search for terms. The error message is

"[parsing_exception] [terms] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [activeIds], with { line=1 & col=63 }"

Active Ids is an array of unique ids. It sort of looks like

```
const activeIds = [ '157621a1-d892-4f4b-80ca-14feddb837a0',
'd04c5c93-a22c-48c3-a3b0-c79a61bdd923',
'296d40d9-f316-4560-bbc9-001d6f46858b',
'2f8c6c37-588d-4d24-9e69-34b6dd7366c2',
'ba0508dd-0e76-4be8-8b6e-9e938ab4abed',
'ab076ed9-1dd5-4987-8842-15f1b995bc0d',
'ea6b0cff-a64f-4ce3-844e-b36d9f161e6f' ]



let items = await es.search({
        "index": table,
        "body": {
          "from": 0, "size": 25,
          "query": {
            "terms" : {
                "growerId" : { 
                    activeIds
                }
            },
            "bool": {
                "must_not": [ 
                    { "match":  
                        { 
                            "active": false
                        }
                    },
                ],
                "must": [
                            { "query_string" : 
                                { 
                                    "query": searchQuery,
                                    "fields": ["item_name"] 
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Appreciate the help!

Edit: Answering this question- "What's the expected result? Can you elaborate and share some sample data? – Nishant Saini 15 hours ago"

I'll try to elaborate a bit.

1) Overall I'm trying to retrieve items that belong to active users. There are 2 tables: `user` and `items`. So I'm initially running an ES that returns all the users that contain `{ active: true }` from the `user` table

2) Running that ES returns an array of ids which I'm calling `activeIds`. The array looks like what I've already displayed in my example. So this works so far (let me know if you want to see the code for that, but if I'm getting an expected result then I don't think we need that now)

3) Now I want to search through the `items` table, and retrieve only the items that contain one of the active ids. So an item should look like:

[image: ITEM]

4) expected result is retrieve an array of objects that match the `growerId` with one of the `activeIds`. So if I do a search query for "flowers", a single expected result should look like:

```
[ { _index: 'items-dev',
_type: 'items-dev_type',
_id: 'itemId=fc68dadf-21c8-43c2-98d2-cf574f71f06d',
_score: 11.397207,
_source: 
{ itemId: 'fc68dadf-21c8-43c2-98d2-cf574f71f06d',
'@SequenceNumber': '522268700000000025760905838',
item_name: 'Flowers',
grower_name: 'Uhs',
image: '630b5d6e-566f-4d55-9d31-6421eb2cff87.jpg',
dev: true,
growerId: 'd04c5c93-a22c-48c3-a3b0-c79a61bdd923',
sold_out: true,
'@timestamp': '2018-12-20T16:09:38.742599',
quantity_type: 'Pounds',
active: true,
pending_inventory: 4,
initial_quantity: 5,
price: 10,
item_description: 'Field of flowers' } },
```

So here the `growerId` matches `activeIds[1]`

But if I do a search for "invisible", which is created by a an inactive user, I get:

```
[ { _index: 'items-dev',
_type: 'items-dev_type',
_id: 'itemId=15200473-93e1-477c-a1a7-0b67831f5351',
_score: 1,
_source: 
{ itemId: '15200473-93e1-477c-a1a7-0b67831f5351',
'@SequenceNumber': '518241400000000004028805117',
item_name: 'Invisible too',
grower_name: 'Field of Greens',
image: '7f37d364-e768-451d-997f-8bb759343300.jpg',
dev: true,
growerId: 'f25040f4-3b8c-4306-9eb5-8b6c9ac58634',
sold_out: false,
'@timestamp': '2018-12-19T20:47:16.128934',
quantity_type: 'Pounds',
pending_inventory: 5,
initial_quantity: 5,
price: 122,
item_description: 'Add' } },
```

Now that `growerId` does not match any of the ids in `activeIds`.

5) Using the code you helped with, it's returning 0 items.

Let me know if you need more detail. I've been working on this for a bit too long :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terms query accept array of terms so the terms query should be defined as below:

```
  "terms": {
    "growerId": activeIds
  }
```

You might face other errors as well after making the above correction. So below is full query which might help you:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 25,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "active": false
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": searchQuery,
            "fields": [
              "item_name"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "growerId": activeIds
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It got rid of the error but now it's not displaying any results. any idea why?

Comment: What's the expected result? Can you elaborate and share some sample data?

Comment: I added more details. Let me know what you think and thanks again!!

Comment: What is the datatype of `growerId`?

Comment: `growerId` is a string

Comment: Thats the reason you are getting 0 results. If the field is string and it is analyzed (which by default uses analyzer `standard`),  it doesn't store the exact id instead it break your ids into multiple terms while `terms query` checks for exact match. Look this to understand more see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510502/match-query-along-with-should-clause-giving-more-than-required-match-results#53511606

Comment: makes sense! thank you so much it seems to be working now. all i did was change `"growerId"` to `"growerId.keyword"` . If it's a simple question for you to answer, I'd love to find out how to retrieve the mapping. Not a big deal if not, I'll go ahead and mark this as answered.

Comment: Assuming the name of your index is `test` to get the mapping of the index make a GET call as `GET test/_mappings` to get the mapping of the index