# Filter document on items in an array ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I am using ElasticSearch to search through documents. However, I need to make sure the current user is able to see those documents. Each document is tied to a community, in which the user may belong.

Here is the mapping for my Document:

```
export const mapping = {
  properties: {
    amazonId: { type: 'text' },
    title: { type: 'text' },
    subtitle: { type: 'text' },
    description: { type: 'text' },
    createdAt: { type: 'date' },
    updatedAt: { type: 'date' },
    published: { type: 'boolean' },
    communities: { type: 'nested' }
  }
}
```

I'm currently saving the ids of the communities the document belongs to in an array of strings. Ex: `["edd05cd0-0a49-4676-86f4-2db913235371", "672916cf-ee32-4bed-a60f-9a7c08dba04b"]`

Currently, when I filter a query with `{term: { communities: community.id } }`, it returns all the documents, regardless of the communities it's tied to.

Here's the full query:

```
{
  index: 'document',
  filter_path: { filter: {term: { communities: community.id } } },
  body: {
    sort: [{ createdAt: { order: 'asc' } }]
  }
}
```

This is the following result based on the community id of `"b7d28e7f-7534-406a-981e-ddf147b5015a"`. **NOTE:** This is a return from my graphql, so the communities on the document are actual full objects after resolving the hits from the ES query.

```
"hits": [
    {
      "title": "The One True Document",
      "communities": [
        {
          "id": "edd05cd0-0a49-4676-86f4-2db913235371"
        },
        {
          "id": "672916cf-ee32-4bed-a60f-9a7c08dba04b"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Boring Document 1",
      "communities": []
    },
    {
      "title": "Boring Document 2",
      "communities": []
    },
    {
      "title": "Unpublished",
      "communities": [
        {
          "id": "672916cf-ee32-4bed-a60f-9a7c08dba04b"
        }
       ]
    }
]
```

When I attempt to map the communities as `{type: 'keyword', index: 'not_analyzed'}` I receive an error that states, `[illegal_argument_exception] Could not convert [communities.index] to boolean`.

So do I need to change my mapping, my filter, or both? Searching around the [docs for 6.6](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/query-dsl-terms-query.html), I see that `terms` needs the `non_analyzed` mapping.

**UPDATE --------------------------**

I updated the communities mapping to be a `keyword` as suggested below. However, I still received the same result.

I updated my query to the following (using a community id that has documents):

```
query: { index: 'document',
  body: 
   { sort: [ { createdAt: { order: 'asc' } } ],
     from: 0,
     size: 5,
     query: 
      { bool: 
         { filter: 
            { term: { communities: '672916cf-ee32-4bed-a60f-9a7c08dba04b' } } } } } }
```

Which gives me the following results:

```
{
  "data": {
    "communities": [
      {
        "id": "672916cf-ee32-4bed-a60f-9a7c08dba04b",
        "feed": {
          "documents": {
            "hits": []
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Appears that my filter is working too well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are storing ids of communities you should make sure that the ids doesn't get analysed. For this `communities` should be of type `keyword`. Second you want to store array of community ids since a user can belong to multiple communities. To do this you don't need to make it of type `nested`. [Nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) has all together different use case.
To sore values as array you need to make sure that while indexing you are always passing the values against the field as array even if the value is single value.

You need to change mapping and the way you are indexing values against field `communities`.

**1. Update mapping as below:**

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "amazonId": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "subtitle": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "createdAt": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "updatedAt": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "published": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "communities": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Adding a document to index:**

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "title": "The One True Document",
  "communities": [
    "edd05cd0-0a49-4676-86f4-2db913235371",
    "672916cf-ee32-4bed-a60f-9a7c08dba04b"
  ]
}
```

**3. Filtering by community id:**

```
GET my_index/_doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "communities": "672916cf-ee32-4bed-a60f-9a7c08dba04b"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

#### Nested Field approach

**1. Mapping:**

```
PUT my_index_2
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "amazonId": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "subtitle": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "createdAt": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "updatedAt": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "published": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "communities": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Indexing document:**

```
PUT my_index_2/_doc/1
{
  "title": "The One True Document",
  "communities": [
    {
      "id": "edd05cd0-0a49-4676-86f4-2db913235371"
    },
    {
      "id": "672916cf-ee32-4bed-a60f-9a7c08dba04b"
    }
  ]
}
```

**3. Querying (used of nested query):**

```
GET my_index_2/_doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "communities",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "communities.id.keyword": "672916cf-ee32-4bed-a60f-9a7c08dba04b"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You might be noticing I used `communities.id.keyword` and not `communities.id`. To understand the reason for this go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510502/match-query-along-with-should-clause-giving-more-than-required-match-results#53511606).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I updated my post with my results from this change. (Essentially, I had the same results). I updated my query and now have no results returned.

Comment: Can you add a document that should have be the part of the result?

Comment: What I feel is that you have added the values against the communities field as array of objects and not as array of ids. Please check the updated answer. If have plan to have more fields other than id for communities then you might have to still go with nested type approach. If this is the case then let me know and I'll add solution for that as well.

Comment: Updated answer for nested type approach as well. Hope this helps and clarify your doubts

Comment: Yes! I was able to get it working! Thank you so much for your help!