# How do I match entries in the elasticsearch containing dashes (-)

Tags: php, elasticsearch

ElasticSearch tokenizes the data.
So "this-that" gets split into 2 tokens.
If it makes a difference, I am using the 6.6 version of ES.
I have documents, that have different fields, such as title, descriptions, name, etc.
In order for us to have a unique identifier, the text in Title "This that" get slugified into "this-that".
I am trying to to query for "this-that" that would return that one document.
I have tried all sorts of things.  I tried suggestions from other questions in this forum, as well as instructions in the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html  page.
Unfortunately, nothing seems to work.
Your help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

$hosts = ['localhost:9200'];
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->setHosts($hosts)
    ->build();

$params = array();

$params = [
    'index' => 'shows',
    'type' => '_doc',
    'body' => [
        'size'=> 10000,
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [ 'match' => [ 'name' => 'this-that'] ],
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$response = $client->search($params);

print_r($response);
?>
```

There are no errors, but it finds all instances with the word "this" and the word "that" in the name field.
I would like to get just the one document back!

Comment: Can you post your config on the `shows` index?

Comment: If you are using default mapping, replace `name` by `name.keyword`, otherwise either update the mapping to add a `keyword` field or change the analyzer of your field.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510502/match-query-along-with-should-clause-giving-more-than-required-match-results#53511606) might help you.

Comment: $params = [
    'index' => 'shows',
    'body' => [
        'settings' => [
            'number_of_shards' => 3,
            'number_of_replicas' => 0,
'index.mapping.ignore_malformed' => true
        ],

Comment: 'mappings' => [
            '_doc' => [
'date_detection' => false,
                'properties' => [
                    'pubdate' => [ 'type' => 'date', 'ignore_malformed' => true ] ,
                    'seasons' => [
                        'properties' => [
                            'episodes' => [
                                'properties' => [
                                    'pubdate' => [ 'type' => 'date', 'ignore_malformed' => true ]
                                ]
                            ]

Comment: ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];  
Sorry would not let me post whole

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the index to list "name" to be of type keyword does not resolve the matter

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment with [analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/analysis-analyzers.html) and [tokenizers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/analysis-tokenizers.html) using Kibana console or http:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_analyze" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{  "analyzer": "standard",  "text": "this-that"}'
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "this",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "that",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_analyze" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{  "analyzer": "keyword",  "text": "this-that"}'
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "this-that",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

To have always exact match for field, you must use keyword-tokenization. You can do it like this:

```
PUT test-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which is exactly same as defining field as a keyword type to begin with:

```
PUT test-index2
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```